# Estrutura HTML - imagem de fundo em CSS

Tags: css

[image: help]

Queria tirar esse branco que fica "sobrando" em modo janela.
Sou novato nisso, qualquer ajuda é bem-vinda.

```
body {
    background-image: url(IMGS/img08.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Comment: Meu caro amigo, por favor edite rapidamente a pergunta, por exemplo, coloque a estrutura HTML que faz referência a esse banner que quer configurar. Ok? Já faço um código rápido pra lhe ajudar ^^

Comment: Ei, sei que você é novato mas não insira uma imagem como background direto no body. Crie primeiro uma tag `header` ou uma `div` normal porque aí você pode definir o tamanho que quiser. Aí dentro dessas tags voce coloca o background-image, ok?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Então amigo,

Você pode seguir e estruturar sua imagem de fundo usando o um `header` ou `div`, conforme abaixo:

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header {
  background: url(https://www.altoastral.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/paisagem.jpg) no-repeat center center/cover;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  
</header>
```

Coloque seu código assim que esse espaço irá sumir.
Até.

Comment: Muito obrigado.

Comment: Funcionou mano? Se sim, marque como correta a resposta para contribuir com outros que irão ter problemas semelhantes no futuro :D

Answer (score 1):

Ao usar a propriedade `background-size: 100%` você está definindo que a largura da imagem de fundo irá ocupar toda a largura do body. Isso porque a propriedade `background-size` pode possuir dois valores:

```
background-size: largura altura
                    ↑      ↑
               1º valor   2º valor
```

No seu caso, apenas a largura foi definida em 100% (1º valor). Com isso, se a altura da janela for maior que a altura da imagem, a imagem não irá ocupar todo o espaço vertical.

Você poderia usar um segundo valor (altura) em 100%, mas isso iria quebrar a proporção da imagem (*aspect ratio*): `background-size: 100% 100%;`

O que você tem que fazer é usar o valor `cover`:

```
background-size: cover;
```

O `cover` irá cobrir toda a área do body até altura total, porém poderá cortar uma parte lateral direita da imagem de fundo, porque ele irá aumentar a imagem até a altura da janela, mantendo a proporção da imagem.

Então, se você achar melhor, poderá usar outra propriedade para manter a imagem centralizada, pois, se houver corte nas laterais, que sejam iguais do lado esquerdo e direito, e não apenas do lado direito:

```
background-position: center;
```

Logo, seu estilo ficará:

```
body {
    background-image: url(IMGS/img08.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#elementoPrincipal {
  height: 100%;
}

#elementoSuperior {
  background-color: #505050;
  height: 30%;
  display: block;
}

#elementoInferior {
  background-color: #707070;
  height: 70%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div id="elementoPrincipal">
    <div id="elementoSuperior"></div>
    <div id="elementoInferior"></div>
  </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Aparentemente, a altura total do elemento com o background não está conseguindo se 'esticar' até a altura da janela: faça o seguinte:

- Deixe os elementos *html* e *body* com height 100%;
- Adicione height 100% ao elemento mãe (o que contêm os outros)
- Defina alturas para os elementos superiores e inferiores, que se baseiem na altura do elemento mãe;
- Vale lembrar que talvez seja a imagem que não esteja cobrindo todo o espaço: troque o background-size para *cover*, para que ocupe todo o espaço disponível.

Comment: Se você desse algum exemplo de como está seu código (HTML e CSS), facilitaria.